# LINQ - Login Database

Tags: c#, linq

I want to login with existing userID and password in database.

When I use SQL statement in C#, I use this code

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM MsUser WHERE Username='"+textBoxUsername.Text+"' and Password='"+textBoxPass.Text+"'";
DataTable dt = con.AdapterQuery(query);
if (dt.Rows.Count>0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Success loging");
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Failed");
```

But i want to use LINQ, what is the code when using LINQ statement??

Comment: LINQ for what exactly? LINQ is not a magic that executes your select query and get it's count of rows.

Comment: _"When I use SQL statement in C#, I use this code"_ you should not use that code because it's open to sql-injection attacks. Instead always parametrize your queries.

Answer (score 0):

You simply read user data for given UserName and Password. In LINQ you can replace this with:

```
var user = Context.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == "userName" && u.Password == "password");

if(user != null)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Success loging");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Failed");
}
```

Comment: is var user = Context.Users.SingleOrDefault() equals datatable with code SELECT * FROM USERS??

Comment: It is equal to SELECT TOP 1 * FROM USERS??

Comment: I am sorry, i am still confused about DataTable in LINQ, also I am still newbie in programming.. Could you please give another example of DataTable in LINQ like DataTable with SQL Statement(DataTable dt = con.AdapterQuery(SELECT * FROM MsUser))???? Thx